# Retrieve ImportDefintion and corresponding Business Unit for each Import Definition

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap, import

I am attempting to Retrieve ImportDefinitions from an Account and would like to know which ImportDefinition belongs to which Business Unit.  I am expecting a property of Client.ID to be a valid Property, but I receive this message when attempting to include Client.ID in my soap request:

```
<OverallStatus>Error: The Request Property(s) ID do not match with the fields of ImportDefinition retrieve</OverallStatus>
```

Is it possible to retrieve ImportDefinitions within an account so that the response contains the Client.Id?  The reason I mentioned that I was expecting Client.Id to be available is because it has been available on all other objects I've Retrieved.

```
<soapenv:Body>
              <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                 <RetrieveRequest>
                    <ObjectType>ImportDefinition</ObjectType>
                    <Properties>AllowErrors</Properties>  
                    <!-- <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>  -->                                        
                    <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties> 
                    <Properties>Description</Properties>              
                   <Properties>EndOfLineRepresentation</Properties>                        
                   <Properties>FileSpec</Properties>
                   <Properties>FileType</Properties>               
                   <Properties>HeaderLines</Properties>
                   <Properties>MaxFileAge</Properties>
                   <Properties>MaxFileAgeScheduleOffset</Properties>   
                   <Properties>MaxImportFrequency</Properties>
                   <Properties>Name</Properties>  
                   <Properties>NullRepresentation</Properties>
                   <Properties>StandardQuotedStrings</Properties>    
                   <Properties>UpdateType</Properties>

                    <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
                 </RetrieveRequest>
              </RetrieveRequestMsg>
           </soapenv:Body>
```

The corresponding help documentation for ImportDefinition:
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/importdefinition/

Answer (score 0):

I received the answer from a helpful resource at SFMC...

```
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>ImportDefinition</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Client.ClientID1</Properties>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
        </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

It needs to be ClientID1 (and not ClientID, which is the method for every other Retrieve).